# Python: Create directory structure according to dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, sequence, directory-structure

In Python, given a dict (list or sequence) as in:

```
d={'a': 9, 'b': 6, 'c': 10],
```

I would like to create, in a clever way, the a directory structure like this:

```
'a_9/b_6/c_10'.
```

Comment: Hello @Waliston. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, i didn't yet. I would make a for loop on dict.keys() and for each iteration create the subdirectory, store it as a string variable in order to create next subdirectory on next for loop iteration. I am aiming to learn a new way for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

def make_dir(dictionary):
  for key, val in dictionary.items():
    new_dir = f"{key}_{val}"
    os.mkdir(new_dir)
    os.chdir(new_dir)
```

**EDIT:** Or even more concise

```py
import os
os.makedirs("/".join(f"{key}_{val}" for key, val in d.items()))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't now the .join() and f"{} formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not strictly ordered in Python (although as of Python `3.6` there is [some level of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)), but if you sorted it (assuming you want that), perhaps by key, you could try something like follows:

```
new_dir = os.path.join(*[f'{k}_{v}' for k, v in sorted(d.items())])
os.makedirs(new_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks @PyPingu . I didn't realize the new interesting feature: OrderedDict on collections. Actually I want to sort dict keys according to some previously chosen separate list with human sorted keys.

Comment: python 3.7.3 complains when issuing 'new_dir = ...' ------------- TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not generator ------------ Can it be solved? I also have tried str(v) instead of v.   @DavidGildour solution worked here.

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed out the unpacking `*`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.